# _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

Sou novo programando em Python e estou fazendo esses programas como forma de estudo.
Tenho 2 códigos onde 1 é a janela principal (`Macro.py`) e a de configuração (`config_window.py`), os dois códigos estão funcionando normalmente, porém, só de dar `import config_window.py` sem adicionar nenhuma outra linha eu já recebo esse código de erro:
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

eu dei uma pesquisada e vi que esse código aparece quando vc tenta reutilizar o `photoimage`, mas eu só utilizo ele no `Macro.py`

`Macro.py`

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter import Button
#import config_window
import pyautogui
import time
import win32gui

class Janela:...

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
raiz = Tk()
raiz.title("MACRO BY MOON")
# raiz.geometry("300x500")
raiz.attributes('-alpha', 0.7)  # Adiciona Transparencia
raiz.attributes('-topmost', True)  # Deixa ela sempre visivel
raiz.resizable(width=False, height=False)

bg = PhotoImage(file="vocations_knight.png")
config_image = PhotoImage(file="config.png")

# criar o canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(raiz, width=300, height=220)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# colocar a img no canvas
my_canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=bg, anchor="nw")

# Colocar a Label
my_canvas.create_text(150, 30, text="Moon's Macro", font=('Verdana', '13', 'bold'))


Janela(raiz)
raiz.mainloop()
```

`config_window.py`

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
import yaml
import io

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Configuração")
gui.attributes('-topmost', True)
# Carregamos o arquivos CFG
stream = open("config.yaml", 'r')
global c,ch,cd
c = yaml.safe_load(stream)
cd = c['CD']
ch = c['HOTKEYS']

# Dimensões Janela

largura = 250
altura = 320

# Resolução do sistema
largura_windows = gui.winfo_screenwidth()
altura_windows = gui.winfo_screenheight()

# Posição da janela

posx = largura_windows / 2 - largura / 2
posy = altura_windows / 2 - altura / 2

# Geometry

gui.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (largura, altura, posx, posy))

gui.resizable(width=False, height=False)
gui.overrideredirect(TRUE)

def salvar():...

# Criando os botões
botao = Button(gui, text='Salvar', command=salvar)
botao.place(x=90, y=290)
botao_sair = Button(gui, text='Sair', command=gui.quit)
botao_sair.place(x=140, y=290)
```

Comment: Por favor adicione um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel) para que possamos reproduzir o problema e identificar uma solução adequada.

Comment: @Rfroes87 adicionei o código dos dois arquivos a parte de criação de janela